# LEFT JOIN on Max Date value with ORDER BY id DESC

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join, maxdate

Suppose I have the following two tables:

```
lead
id(PK) status   assigned_to   date
1      open     Smith         2018-08-26
2      open     Drew          2018-08-26
3      new      Amit          2018-08-26

lead_comments
id  lead_id(FK)  comment_data        follow_up_time
1      1         old task line2      2018-08-27 14:18:26
2      2         old task line1      2018-08-27 14:18:26
3      1         new task line1      2018-08-27 17:18:00
4      2         new task line3      2018-09-27 20:18:26
5      2         old task line2      2018-08-27 21:18:26
```

Now, I need an MySQL query that would select **each lead matches with the latest comment** (if present) **Order By latest `follow_up_time`** from the lead_comments table.

My Expected Result:

```
lead_id comment _id follow_up_time       comment_data    assigned_to    
2        4          2018-09-27 20:18:26  new task line3  Drew          
1        3          2018-08-27 17:18:00  new task line1  Smith
3        Null       Null                 Null            Amit
```

I am trying this:

```
SELECT l.id as lead_id,
       l.status as status,
       c.id as comment_id,
       c.comment_date as comment_date, 
       c.comment_data as comment,
       c.commented_by,
       l.assigned_to 
FROM lms_leads l 
LEFT JOIN lms_leads_comments as c ON l.id=c.lead_id 
JOIN (
    SELECT max(cm.id) as id
    FROM lms_leads_comments cm
    GROUP BY cm.lead_id 
) as cc ON c.id=cc.id 
GROUP BY l.id 
ORDER BY c.follow_up_time DESC
```

However, this query does not work as per my expected result

Please suggest how I can achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: why isn't `old task line2` the latest comment `for lead_id = 2`

Comment: because follow_up_time is 2018-08-27 21:18:26 < 2018-09-27 20:18:26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (for MySQL version < 8.0):

```
select @rn := 1, @lead_id_lag := 0;

select l.id lead_id, 
       lc.id comment_id,
       lc.follow_up_time,
       lc.comment_data,
       l.assigned_to
from lead l
left join (
    select case when @lead_id_lag = lead_id then @rn := @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end rn,
           @lead_id_lag := lead_id,
           id,
           follow_up_time,
           comment_data,
           lead_id
    from lead_comments
    order by lead_id, follow_up_time desc
) lc on l.id = lc.lead_id and lc.rn = 1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/47Tk86VGfpLHeQZyS5KFXx/0)

Comment: its not giving me expeted result check this : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f24cf771eab1a24de5aa6d209bfe5df4

Comment: @amitgupta Did you try the demo I posted?  This site supports MySQL better and there it works.

Comment: yes i have tried your demo but its giving me an unexpected error occurred during click on run button :(

Comment: @amitgupta it's not possible, it works when I enter the site. Dud you try changing anything?

Comment: ohh there was my browere problem. yes it working now thanks :)

Comment: @amitgupta Then you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: can we count total number of comments present on each lead with this query itself ? please also help me with that, it will help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`(MySQL 8.0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT l.*, c.comment_data, c.follow_up_time,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l.id ORDER BY c.follow_up_time DESC) AS rn
      FROM lms_leads l 
      LEFT join lms_leads_comments as c ON l.id=c.lead_id) s
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56672381c0a67d0a2174d4b40bb873a5)

Comment: its giving me error : right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY l.id ORDER BY c.follow_up_time DESC) AS rn
      FROM lms_leads l' at line 3

Comment: @amitgupta MySQL 8.0 and above

Comment: can we achieve it on MySQL Server version: 5.6.40

Comment: its not giving me expeted result : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f24cf771eab1a24de5aa6d209bfe5df4

Comment: @amitgupta [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60444140c11e342b7c36ae5495f34a1d) - when you copy code- make sure you copied everything